# Rails Simple-Form group_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I came across the following on the simple_form github repo:

```
f.input :country_id, :collection => @continents, :as => :grouped_select, :group_method =>   :countries
```

The thing that caught my attention was the `:group_method` wich would be exceptionally usefull when creating a selectbox that gives options based on what's in the database. The only thing I can't work out is what kind of input the `:group_method` expects, and where to put the method.

For instance, I want to create a selectbox for the table column `:product_type`. I imagine I would write something like this in my simple form:

```
= f.input :product_type_contains, :collection => @products, :as => :grouped_select, :group_method => :product_types
```

where `:product_type` would be the method that is being called. But I don't know what kind of method I should write, what kind of result simple_form expects, and if I should put it in the Product class, `Product.rb`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [test suite](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/test/inputs/grouped_collection_select_input_test.rb), **simple_form** seems to expect the type of arrays or hashes that you would use with grouped_options_for_select:

```
test 'grouped collection accepts group_label_method option' do
  with_input_for @user, :tag_ids, :grouped_select,
    :collection => { ['Jose', 'Carlos'] => 'Authors' },
  :group_method => :first,
  :group_label_method => :last
  [...]

test 'grouped collection accepts label and value methods options' do
  with_input_for @user, :tag_ids, :grouped_select,
    :collection => { 'Authors' => ['Jose', 'Carlos'] },
    :group_method => :last,
    :label_method => :upcase,
    :value_method => :downcase
  [...]
```

Presumably, you could write a class method on `Product.rb` that creates a structure similar, or even try using grouped_options_for_select(@products)...

Hope this gets you on the right path.